# RxJava2 - Interval on a repetitive task & run an observable on a conditional

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-java2

Running with retrofit

This is my interface:

```
  @GET("solicitation/all")
  Observable<SolicitationResponse> getAll(@Query("X-Authorization") String apiKey);
```

This is where I run it:

```
    apiService.getAll(getResources().getString(R.string.api_key))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .flatMapIterable(SolicitationResponse::getData)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .delay(5L, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS) // THIS DOESN'T WORK LIKE I WANT IT TO..
            .repeat()
            .subscribe(s -> Log.e(TAG, "data: " + s.getName()));
```

---

## So, two questions:

**1)** How can I add a conditional to only run if we have internet connection?

This doesn't work:

```
if (NetworkUtils.isConnected()) {
    //observable above here
}
```

Why? Because the conditional code doesn't run itself endlessly, which means it will only check if we have internet connection once, ergo, it will crash if we lose it.

Is there any way to add a conditional before running the getAll method?

**2)** I need to add an interval before or after the task, by inserting `.delay` it will delay the subscription, which is not what I want or need. How can I accomplish it in this particular situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a suggestion:

```
Observable.fromCallable(() -> NetworkUtils.isConnected())
            .flatMap(isConnected -> {
                if (isConnected) {
                    return apiService.getAll(getResources().getString(R.string.api_key))
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .flatMapIterable(SolicitationResponse::getData);
                } else {
                    return Observable.empty();
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.immediate())
            .repeatWhen(observable -> observable.delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
            .subscribe(s -> Log.e(TAG, "data: " + s.getName()));
```

1) the most straightforward way is to add the network check to the stream and using flatMap() conditionally decide what to do further.

2) adding delay before can be done using `delaySubscription()` with the desired value, but then the delay will happen also with the first time, so the second approach of adding delay at the end seems more appropriate here, and can be done using `repeatWhen()`

Comment: Awesome,thanks. Question though, how can I unsubscribe when activity is destroyed?

Comment: Just unsubscribe, it will stop the loop

Comment: @yosriz do you need to extra subscribeOn io in the flatmapped observable? I think it's unnecessary.

Comment: @HabibOkanla, if you want parallelism - then yes, otherwise all service call will happen at the same single background IO thread sequentially.